# Angular 7 8 9 after ng build --prod API is not working

Tags: angular, angular7, angular8

Angular 7 8 9 after ng build API is proper working but , after --prod build its not working, i checkd before post API url is proper pass , but not hit...

service file:

```
register(userData: RegisterUser): Observable<RegisterUserResponse>{
 return this.http.post<RegisterUserResponse>(this.apiRoutes.signup, userData);
}
```

---

environment file :

```
const serverUrl = 'http://roo2.in';
export const environment = {
  serverUrl: `${serverUrl}`,
  apiUrl: `${serverUrl}/api`,
  production: true
}
```

Comment: Do you get any errors in the console or the network inspector? Maybe CORS related?

Comment: no, i didn't get any error on my console, but simple (ng build)  project its working properly....

Comment: after Hit API , I checked network , but not show any API hitting , it's total empty..so  i thing it's not cross related problem , because all cross related error show on consoles.

Answer (score 0):

Based on your comment if url is passed correctly and not hit on, it could be that you didn't subscribe to your observable

```
register(userData: RegisterUser): Observable<RegisterUserResponse>{
 return this.http.post<RegisterUserResponse>(this.apiRoutes.signup, userData);
}
```

somewhere else you needed to

```
  this.xxxService.register(someData).subscribe(result => console.log(result))
```

Comment: actually sir , my URL is proper pass in services , but not hit on : -                                    
   return this.http.post<LoginResponse>(`http://roo2.in/api/login`, userData)

Answer (score 0):

HTTP_INTERCEPTORS issue.  after remove INTERCEPTORS it's working properly on --prod build

---

```
providers: [
// {
//   provide: HTTP_INTERCEPTORS,
//   useClass: InterceptorService,
//   multi: true
// }]
```